# Django: getting rid of RemovedInDjango19Warning for contenttypes

Tags: python, django

I'd like to get rid of this warning the "right" way, by ensuring I'm ready to update to Django 1.9 when it arrives.

The deprecation warning I get is the following:

```
/Users/.../south/modelsinspector.py:20: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
```

I've done a complete search of my project for the phrase `django.contrib.contenttypes`, and the only place I can find it is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

However, when I remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS` (not sure that I really should be doing that!), I get yet a different DeprecationWarning:

```
/Users/.../django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py:159: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
class ContentType(models.Model):
```

What is the right thing for me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the message is telling you that the problem is coming from the app South, not your code base.

Usually, the correct way to prevent the deprecation error would be to upgrade the app to a version that has fixed the problem. Sometimes, that might not be possible if a new version hasn't been released yet.

However, in this case, I don't know why you have South installed at all. For Django 1.7+, you should be using Django's built in migrations. Have you tried removing `'south'` from your installed apps?

Comment: Hmm, `south` wasn't in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, so not quite sure why it was complaining. I did a `pip uninstall south` and restarted Django with `foreman`, and it went away. Guess that works!